# Wicket IFormValidator - Mark multiple FormComponents as invalid

Tags: java, wicket

I have an `IFormValidator` that checks if the values of multiple `FormComponents` are coherent.

Now if validation fails, I'd like to highlight **all** related FormComponents and respective HTML `label` tags, just like it happens with Validators, that are responsible for only a single FormComponent (e.g. `StringValidator`).

My first try was calling `FormComponent#invalid()` on all related FormComponents, but that doesn't seem to do the trick, since it just calls `FormComponent#onInvalid()`, which does nothing by default.

The second thing I tried was calling `FormComponent#error(String)` on each component but that of course generates an additional error message for each FormComponent, which is not the desired behaviour. But at least it does highlight the individual invalid FormComponents.

What would be the correct way to do this? Is there a simple way I'm overlooking, since the `IFormValidator#getDependentFormComponents()` method, which I'm supposed to implement, already tells the Validator, which FormComponents will be invalid as a result failing the validation?

Here is a stripped down example of what I tried with Wicket 8.3:

```
wicketForm.add(new IFormValidator() {

        @Override
        public FormComponent<?>[] getDependentFormComponents() {
            return new FormComponent<?>[] {formComponent1, formComponent2, formComponent3};
        }

        @Override
        public void validate(Form<?> form) {
            if (/*values of formComponent1-3 are not coherent*/) {
                form.error("<error message>");

                /* No highlighting at all */
                formComponent1.invalid();
                formComponent2.invalid();
                formComponent3.invalid();

                /* Highlighting works, but obviously produces same error message multiple times */
                formComponent1.error("<error message>");
                formComponent2.error("<error message>");
                formComponent3.error("<error message>");
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: How are you displaying the error messages? With a FeedbackPanel?

Comment: Yes, a `FencedFeedbackPanel` to be precise

Comment: Hmm, my first idea would be to try and have the FeedbackPanel not display duplicate messages for example by using a IFeedbackMessageFilter. But I'd have to try and see if it possible for myself first.

Comment: Hm, worth a try, though I might run into problems with these messages being shown somewhere else, when that specific FeedbackPanel is filtering / not showing these duplicated messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A FormComponent is deemed as invalid only when its `#error()` methods are called - see `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent#isValid()`.

If you want to show only the error feedback message of the Form then you need to instantiate your FeedbackPanel as:

```
new FencedFeedbackPanel("id", new ComponentFeedbackMessageFilter(form));
```

This way it will render the feedback messages only of the Form.

You can use the feedback messages of the form components to show their specific errors next to the respective HTML form element (`input`, `select`, etc.)

Comment: Ok, so for my given example using `ComponentFeedbackMessageFilter` works, so I'm accepting this answer. But since this also got rid of individual error messages from for example required fields (`setRequired(true)`), I went with reporting empty strings (`error("")`) on the indiviual components in the `IFormValidator` and then writing a custom `IFeedbackMessageFilter`, that does only accept messages with a length greater than 0.